# Point out errors in a company's website during interview

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, job-search, software-development

Today I was preparing for an in person interview at a startup company and happened to notice a couple of inconsistencies in their website (inconsistent product launch dates, some typos in unit conversions). I am considering whether I should inform them about these at the end of the in person interview. I wouldn't do that at a larger company, they have quality control processes and a lot of employees that will catch it eventually. But if I was an employee at the startup I would welcome the feedback.

I was first looking at their website a month ago, when I applied for the job and already noticed the inconsistencies back then. So I believe they are unaware of the typos. I don't want to come across as smug or as a stickler, but those errors are on their product page and easily obvious to potential clients.

Its a small start up company and I have single-handedly maintained websites in the past and know how incredibly difficult it is too keep information consistent across all pages.

Is bringing the typos up a bad idea?

**Edit 1:** 
The question is different from [How do I tell the interviewer their company website is done wrong during a phone interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13584/how-do-i-tell-the-interviewer-their-company-website-is-done-wrong-during-a-phone) as I am bringing this information up unsolicited.

The question is also different from [Pointing out flaws in their website?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/96297/pointing-out-flaws-in-their-website) as the website is not under construction and the errors have persisted for a month.

The question is also different from
[I have noticed that a potential employer's website has been compromised - should I mention it during an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/i-have-noticed-that-a-potential-employers-website-has-been-compromised-should) since the website isn't hacked. It is not a security critical issue.

Comment: I would disagree on that @gnat typos are hardly "compromising" a website as that other question does (it talks about actual hacking)

Comment: See also: [Pointing out flaws in their website?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/96297/pointing-out-flaws-in-their-website)

Comment: @David K. I saw the post, but the employer wasn't asking me about their website. I am bringing this up unsolicited.

Comment: @David K. As for the second post, the website isn't under construction. The error has persistet for over a month

Comment: If you're interviewing for a QA position, it's a great idea!

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a Q/A position, but a software engineering job for one of their products.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is bringing the typos up a bad idea?

**Perhaps during the interview is not the best time to bring that up.**

I suggest you proceed with the recruiting process, and then act upon the following scenarios:

1. *You get hired* - In this case you will be in a better position to bring up those typos you found, as you now will be working for that company and saying such things would be part of your responsibilities.
2. *You don't get hired* - Then, when you reply back to them (on their rejection email or similar) kindly point out those typos and thank them for their time.

   Of course, another option is just to thank them but don't point out the typos to be safe. However, if the remarks are done politely and constructively then pointing them can hardly go wrong.

Comment: I'd be hesitant with #2. It might just come across as being vindictive (*Fine, you don't want to hire me. I think your website sucks.*) Better to just say nothing and let them deal with their own problems.

Comment: @DavidK well that may be your style, but if this is done **kindly** and politely then I see no problem in pointing so... but you have a point, saying nothing is an option

Comment: I think the only exception where you'd bring this up in an interview if you are specifically being hired for a QA position, and your job performance will be based on bringing errors like these to attention.  In this case, helping the company understand the kind of experience you bring to the table will be beneficial.

Comment: If it is a small company and they can't handle this kind of feedback, do you really want to work for them?